# Tabula Java Heap Error — only 1 page to convert

Tags: java, pdf, heap-memory, tabula

I want to extract tables from 1 page pdf (50 KB) using Tabula, but it returns this error:

```
2022-01-08 17:33:25.054:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@47089e5f{/,file:/C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-tabula.jar-_-any-6136871881336378357.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{file:/H:/Course/tabula-win-1.2.1/tabula/tabula.jar}
2022-01-08 17:33:25.056:WARN:oejsh.RequestLogHandler:main: !RequestLog
2022-01-08 17:33:25.068:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@2bb0e277{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2022-01-08 17:33:25.069:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @8398ms
2022-01-08 17:33:35.840:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1706234378-18: Error for /documents
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.jruby.util.ByteList.ensure(ByteList.java:341)
        at org.jruby.util.io.EncodingUtils$1.resize(EncodingUtils.java:1197)
        at org.jruby.util.io.EncodingUtils.moreOutputBuffer(EncodingUtils.java:1513)
        at org.jruby.util.io.EncodingUtils.transcodeLoop(EncodingUtils.java:1415)
        at org.jruby.util.io.EncodingUtils.transcodeLoop(EncodingUtils.java:1312)
        at org.jruby.util.io.EncodingUtils.strTranscode0(EncodingUtils.java:936)
        at org.jruby.util.io.EncodingUtils.strTranscode(EncodingUtils.java:857)
        at org.jruby.util.io.EncodingUtils.strEncode(EncodingUtils.java:829)
        at org.jruby.RubyString.encode(RubyString.java:5398)
        at json.ext.Parser.convertEncoding(Parser.java:196)
        at json.ext.Parser.initialize(Parser.java:175)
        at json.ext.Parser$INVOKER$i$0$1$initialize.call(Parser$INVOKER$i$0$1$initialize.gen)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:725)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:208)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:741)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:278)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:79)
        at org.jruby.RubyObject.callInit(RubyObject.java:348)
        at json.ext.Parser.newInstance(Parser.java:151)
        at json.ext.Parser$INVOKER$s$0$1$newInstance.call(Parser$INVOKER$s$0$1$newInstance.gen)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:212)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:208)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:338)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:183)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:324)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:74)
        at org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.interpret(InterpreterEngine.java:84)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:179)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:165)
        at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:200)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:318)
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:155)
```

I've already tried multiple times to reinstall both Java and Tabula, restarted the whole computer, cleared the "Local/Temp" folder, cleared ports and changed 8080 to 9999, but nothing happens.

The pfd is 100% valid — I have opened it this morning without any trouble but then suddenly it just stopped working. Since then it returns "Sorry, your file upload could not be processed. Please double-check that the file you uploaded is a valid PDF file and try again" — and I cannot see any of my previous files, it just shows "First time using Tabula? Welcome!"

OS: Windows 10

I will be very grateful for any help

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Unfortunately, increasing of heap size didn't help either. I've traced the memory usage with Java profiler and noticed that the error happens synchronically with a sudden peak of Garbage Collector activity. Idk how to interpret it because I can't spot any garbage folder to clean it. Deleting Temporary Files using Java Control Panel didn't help either. And another interesting point: according to Java Profiler, memory usage doesn't exceed 1 GB — and I've read that the default maximum is 2 GB.

Comment: Thank you again for your help! Wish you all the best things in the world ☀️

P.S. Deleted first version of my comments because spotted some grammar mistakes